# Apps from unknown developers can sometimes be unsafe

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-keystore

After generate signed APK (Release Version 1.0) ,i tried to test it in my phone but i get this message

> Play Protect doesn't recognize this app's developer. Apps from unknown developers can sometimes be unsafe.

i don't know why i get it , i have released to many apps without problem, but in this one i get this message , i tried to create a new key-store also i tried to create a new project with different package name but i still facing the same issue.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is just because you tried to install your app directly from APK, and the device or Play Protect can't verify your developer's ID. You can try to upload your apk to Google Play Store then install it from there to see if the problem still persists or not.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play protect recognizes the developer from the signing key the app is signed with. You can [learn more about App Signing here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing). Google Play protect gets this information from the key used to publish the App in Google Play.

Most new apps are enrolled in Google Play App Signing ([Help article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423)). You don't say whether yours is or not, but I suspect it is. That is a good thing - it lets Google Help you if you lose your signing key or it gets compromised.

To see what the experience will be for your users, the best thing to do is use an Internal Testing Track when you publish your app during development. The release process is almost instant. And it lets you get the exact same experience your users will get, as the app is downloaded from Google Play, signed with the same key, etc. 
You can find [more about Internal Test Tracks here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213).